# Session Expires Immediately With Shiro 1.3.2 and JBoss EAP 7.1 Combination

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, shiro

I'm upgrading from JBoss EAP 6.4.x to JBoss EAP 7.1 and using Shiro 1.3.2. Currently I have a problem where a session will be created upon the initial visit of the deployed webapp and the session will have the host name appended to it before logging in.

The following is what I believe to be a relevant snippet of my shiro.ini:

```
# SESSION MANAGEMENT #
sessionManager = org.myapp.custom.CustomDefaultWebSessionManager
sessionManager.sessionIdUrlRewritingEnabled = false
securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager
# 3,600,000 milliseconds = 1 hour
securityManager.sessionManager.globalSessionTimeout = 900000

cacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager
securityManager.cacheManager = $cacheManager

authc = org.myapp.custom.CustomFormAuthenticationFilter
authc.loginUrl = /login.html
authc.successUrl = /main.html

authc.usernameParam = username
authc.passwordParam = password
logout.redirectUrl = /loggedout.html


[urls]
/images/** = anon
/scripts/** = anon
/styles/** = anon
/stylesheet.css = anon
/loggedout.html = anon
/logout = logout
/** = authc
```

The stacktrace I'm getting looks like the following

```
15:04:59,328 DEBUG [org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager] (default task-102) Resolved SubjectContext context session is invalid.  Ignoring and creating an anonymous (session-less) Subject instance.: org.apache.shiro.session.UnknownSessionException: There is no session with id [11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111.hostname]
    at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.eis.AbstractSessionDAO.readSession(AbstractSessionDAO.java:170)
    at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.DefaultSessionManager.retrieveSessionFromDataSource(DefaultSessionManager.java:236)
    at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.DefaultSessionManager.retrieveSession(DefaultSessionManager.java:222)
    at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.AbstractValidatingSessionManager.doGetSession(AbstractValidatingSessionManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.AbstractNativeSessionManager.lookupSession(AbstractNativeSessionManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.AbstractNativeSessionManager.getSession(AbstractNativeSessionManager.java:140)
    at org.apache.shiro.mgt.SessionsSecurityManager.getSession(SessionsSecurityManager.java:156)
    at org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager.resolveContextSession(DefaultSecurityManager.java:456)
    at org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager.resolveSession(DefaultSecurityManager.java:442)
    at org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager.createSubject(DefaultSecurityManager.java:338)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.Subject$Builder.buildSubject(Subject.java:846)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.subject.WebSubject$Builder.buildWebSubject(WebSubject.java:148)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.createSubject(AbstractShiroFilter.java:292)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:359)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:326)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:812)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

While debugging, I would have expected the sessionid `11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111` to persist, but a new session named `11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111.hostname` is being created and checked against the sessionDAO instead -- it contains the former but not the latter.

[Here is the relevant sessionId check snippet from Github.](https://github.com/apache/shiro/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/shiro/session/mgt/DefaultSessionManager.java#L235)

Does anyone have any clue as to why my sessions are generated normally **initially**, and append my hostname to them **shortly after**, preventing me from logging in?

This was not an issue in JBoss 6.4.x. While I understand that upgrading from JBoss EAP 6.4.x to 7.1 is a hefty leap, I'm not understanding why this could be happening.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can manage your sessions, either by the container, or let Shiro manage them: https://shiro.apache.org/web.html#servlet-container-sessions
It looks like your container is at minimum appending the `.host` (possibly to configure sticky sessions?)